# ASP.Net Session Sate , Sharepoint, GAC & Bin deployment

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, moss, wss, session-state

Does the same process apply for session state when a dll is placed in the bin as when placed in the GAC?

Or is there some type of esoteric change that take place under the hood?

I’ve got a test solution deployed to the bin directory of my sharepoint site that uses session state. I made sure that session state is configured in my web.config file...

```
<add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" />

enableSessionState="true"
```

Everything works fine!

Then I copied this project into another solution that is deployed to the GAC and activated on a different sharepoint site. I make sure to turn on session state in the web.config file for this different sharepoint site. I browse to my page that uses session state and get this error…

*Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also make sure that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is included in the \ section in the application configuration.*

Marvelous! The only difference as I can see it is that one solution is deployed to the Bin folder and the other is deployed to the GAC.

Some days I hate Sharepoint.

**Update on this:** I created a simple sharepoint solution with one page that’s deployed to the GAC, this page adds a value to a session variable and then reads it back from the session variable into a label control.

I deployed the solution to my test and production site, It work as expected in the test site but produces the error…

*Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also make sure that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is included in the \ section in the application configuration.*

On my production site, why, why, why?

I checked and rechecked my web.config file and central admin to make sure session state is enabled. This now seems to point to a problem with my sharepoint web app.

**Update on this 2:** It's the master page! I’ve just found by switching the master page to an out of the box choice allows my code to run correctly - which uses session variables. I've also noticed the custom master page doesn't like the 'autoeventwireup=true' page directive. I've done a text comparison between the two master pages and can see nothing different in the Tagprefix. I'll continue looking...

**Update 3**
It's probably easier to close this question and start a new one with some additional information.

[New question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109155/sharepoint-master-pages-and-session-state)

Comment: Just wondering, do you have multiple WFEs in production but not in test?

Comment: Exactly, are you running sessionstate on multiple WFE's in-process, because that won't work I think.

Comment: No, this is a single server farm - only one WFE. I think i'll have to recreate the web app and import the site collection.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible there are some controls on the OOTB master and not on your own master? Maybe there's a problem there. Furthermore, your custom master, does that also have a custom code-behind?

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified if "**Enable Session State**" is checked in **Sharepoint Central Administration (Application Management)**? It will not work unless this is switched on.